# How to create module for security group in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I have this resource to make security groups and have several entry rules.

These files are inside the "security-group" folder because I have to create a module for it.

**Main.tf**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
   name   = var.sg_name

   dynamic "ingress" {
       for_each = local.ingress_rules

       content {
           description = ingress.value.description
           from_port   = ingress.value.port
           to_port     = ingress.value.port
           protocol    = "tcp"
           cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
       }
   }
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
locals {
   ingress_rules = [{
       port        = 443
       description = "Port 443"
   },
   {
       port        = 80
       description = "Port 80"
   }]
}
```

Now outside of the modules/security-group/ folder I have the main .tf file where I want to call that module to create security groups.

```
module "security_group" {
 source = "./modules/security-group"

   dynamic "ingress" {
       for_each = local.ingress_rules

       content {
           description = ingress.value.description
           from_port   = ingress.value.port
           to_port     = ingress.value.port
           protocol    = "tcp"
           cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
       }
   }
}
```

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 29, in module "security_group":
│   29:         dynamic "ingress" {
│
│ Blocks of type "dynamic" are not expected here.
╵
```

How else can I call this module to create the rules and other necessary things? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no dynamic blocks for modules. You have to pass your rules as regular variables to the module, not local values:

```
variable "ingress_rules" {
  default = [{
       from_port   = 443
       to_port     = 443
       description = "Port 443"
   },
   {
       from_port   = 80
       to_port     = 80
       description = "Port 80"
   }]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
   name   = var.sg_name

   dynamic "ingress" {
       for_each = var.ingress_rules

       content {
           description = ingress.value.description
           from_port   = ingress.value.from_port   
           to_port     = ingress.value.to_port     
           protocol    = "tcp"
           cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
       }
   }
}
```

then in parent folder:

```
module "security_group" {
 source = "./modules/security-group"

 ingress_rules =    [
       {
           description =  "description"
           from_port   = 20
           to_port     = 20
           protocol    = "tcp"
           cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
     }
   ] 
}
```

You have to **fix all those names** of your attributes. You can't just mix `port` and `to_port`.